# pass lambda expression as method parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I want to create the following method which takes in a lambda expression and orders data by  it. I can't seem to correctly set this up.

Would look something like this where ??? is the lambda expression:

```
public static MyList<T> PageAndSort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, ???)
```

Would be used like this:

```
MyList.PageAndSort(List<MyEntity> data, x=>x.ChildEntity.Name)
```

Comment: The Tags say c# .. so we can assume :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ has a pretty similar method: [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx). Look at its signature and imitate it:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

Applied to your case:

```
public static MyList<TSource> PageAndSort<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> data,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector
)
```

`Func<T, TResult>` is a delegate with one parameter of type `T` that returns a `TResult`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Action<T>` or `Func<T>` depending of if you require return param or not.

So:

```
public static MyList<T> PageAndSort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Action<T> sortBy)
```

where `T` is replaced by the type you want to sort by, so sting etc.

Comment: Grrr, it wont let me add Action<T> note: Action has a < T > type after it.

Comment: `Func<T>` has no input, and `Action<T>` doesn't fit either, since you need a result that can be used as key for sorting.